# VB.NET pinvoke declaration wrong?

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I copied and pasted the following VB.NET structure from the pinvoke website.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/BITMAPINFOHEADER.html

However when I paste it into a module under the module name like this, VB.NET is telling me that a declaration is expected:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module modDrawing

    StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>Public Structure BITMAPINFOHEADER
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public biSize As Int32
    <FieldOffset(4)> Public biWidth As Int32
    <FieldOffset(8)> Public biHeight As Int32
    <FieldOffset(12)> Public biPlanes As Int16
    <FieldOffset(14)> Public biBitCount As Int16
    <FieldOffset(16)> Public biCompression As Int32
    <FieldOffset(20)> Public biSizeImage As Int32
    <FieldOffset(24)> Public biXPelsperMeter As Int32
    <FieldOffset(28)> Public biYPelsPerMeter As Int32
    <FieldOffset(32)> Public biClrUsed As Int32
    <FieldOffset(36)> Public biClrImportant As Int32
End Structure
```

Where did I go wrong, please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one: (not a full code)

```
    Module modDrawing

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
        Public Structure BITMAPINFOHEADER
            <FieldOffset(0)> Public biSize As Int32
            <FieldOffset(4)> Public biWidth As Int32
            <FieldOffset(8)> Public biHeight As Int32
            <FieldOffset(12)> Public biPlanes As Int16
            <FieldOffset(14)> Public biBitCount As Int16
            <FieldOffset(16)> Public biCompression As Int32
            <FieldOffset(20)> Public biSizeImage As Int32
            <FieldOffset(24)> Public biXPelsperMeter As Int32
            <FieldOffset(28)> Public biYPelsPerMeter As Int32
            <FieldOffset(32)> Public biClrUsed As Int32
            <FieldOffset(36)> Public biClrImportant As Int32
        End Structure

   End Module
```

Comment: Could you perhaps also tell me how to instantiate it? I am not really sure how to do this Marshall(SizeOf( as stated on the website.

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(BITMAPINFOHEADER))

Answer (score 0):

The error in the pinvoke.net code is that the attribute is missing the initial `<`. Instead of

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
```

it should read

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
```

However, `LayoutKind.Explicit` is not really very sensible here. Sure you can specify all the field offset, but why make it hard for yourself? Use `LayoutKind.Sequential`. Since that is the default, you can simply omit the attribute.

```
Public Structure BITMAPINFOHEADER
    Public biSize As Int32
    Public biWidth As Int32
    Public biHeight As Int32
    Public biPlanes As Int16
    Public biBitCount As Int16
    Public biCompression As Int32
    Public biSizeImage As Int32
    Public biXPelsperMeter As Int32
    Public biYPelsPerMeter As Int32
    Public biClrUsed As Int32
    Public biClrImportant As Int32
End Structure
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not experienced with the pinvoke style API declarations. Since those are mostly shown on top of the pinvoke website, I thought that this was the new style that it should be done.